# Android Opengl Circle Texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping, texture2d, render-to-texture

I have been trying to add texture but the texture looks like below:

[image: texture image]

[image: Desire Output]

Here's my code to add coordinate and add texture coordinate.

```
for(int i=0; i<outerVertexCount; i++) {
    float percent=(i/(float)(outerVertexCount));
    float rad= (float) (percent*2*Math.PI);
    float outerX= (float) (centerX+radius*Math.cos(rad));
    float outerY=(float)(centerY+radius*Math.sin(rad));

    int previous=idx;
    circleCoordinates[idx++]=outerX;
    circleCoordinates[idx++]=outerY;
    circleCoordinates[idx++]=(circleCoordinates[previous])/(radius*2);
    circleCoordinates[idx++] = (circleCoordinates[previous+1])/(radius*2);
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: So what is the problem that you are facing? What is the desired output?

Comment: Hi I have edit the question I put my desire output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing a circle and using 'normalized' almost same coordinates to take texture coordinates. So what you need to do is to normalize texture coordinates to the texture space [0, 1]. Easiest way is to check if texture coordinate of top and left should be (0.5, 0.0) and (0.0, 0.5) respectively. Also bottom and right should be (0.5, 1.0) and (1.0, 0.5) respectively. (Points that touches the edges).

The problem in your code is:

```
  circleCoordinates[idx++] = (circleCoordinates[previous])/(radius*2);
  circleCoordinates[idx++] = (circleCoordinates[previous+1])/(radius*2);
```

As you are creating the points in the circle these will go below 0, in some quadrants which will take wrong texture points.
Also you offset your circle by `centerX and centerY` which also moves your texture.

The working code should be:

```
  circleCoordinates[idx++] = (circleCoordinates[previous])/(radius*2) + 0.5 -  centerX / (radius * 2);
  circleCoordinates[idx++] = (circleCoordinates[previous+1])/(radius*2) + 0.5 - centerY / (radius * 2);
```

0.5 is due to you have normalized it using `radius * 2` without centerPoint addition it will map to [-0.5, 0.5] however you also added your center point and also normalized it so you have to subtract `center(XY) / (radius * 2)` to remove the artifact.

TLDR; Your (0,0) is the white intersection in your first image you want it top,left. Normalize accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exemple :

```
public class Circle {

private int[] textureIDs = new int[1];

private int numberOfVertices = 30;


private final float[][] vertices = new float[numberOfVertices][2];
private final float[][] texVertices = new float[numberOfVertices][2];


private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer; // Buffer for vertex-array
private FloatBuffer texBuffer;    // Buffer for texture-coords-array (NEW)


public Circle() {
    setUpVertices(1.0f);
    // Setup vertex-array buffer. Vertices in float. A float has 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4 * 2);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // Convert byte buffer to float

    // Loop through the vertices and put them in the vertexbuffer
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices[i][j]); // Copy data into buffer
        }
    }
    vertexBuffer.position(0); // Rewind

    setUpTextureVertices(1.0f);

    // Setup texture-coords-array buffer, in float. An float has 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4 * 2);
    tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
    // Loop through the vertices and put them in the vertexbuffer
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
            texBuffer.put(texVertices[i][j]); // Copy data into buffer
        }
    }
    texBuffer.position(0);
}


public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);    // Front face in counter-clockwise orientation
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);    // Cull the back face (don't display)

    // Enable vertex-array and define its buffer
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); // Enable texture-coords-array
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define texture-coords


    // Draw the primitives from the vertex-array directly

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, numberOfVertices);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);

}


public void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]); // Bind to texture ID
    // Set up texture filters
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // Construct an input stream to texture image
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.circle);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        // Read and decode input as bitmap
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream);
    } finally {
        try {
            istream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture ID
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
}

private void setUpTextureVertices(float radius) {
    float theta0 = (float) (2 * Math.PI / (numberOfVertices - 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {

        float theta = i * theta0;

        float c = (float) Math.cos(theta);
        float s = (float) Math.sin(theta);

        float x = radius * c;
        float y = radius * s;

        texVertices[i][0] = (x * 0.5f) + 0.5f;
        texVertices[i][1] = (y * 0.5f) + 0.5f;

    }
}

private void setUpVertices(float radius) {
    float theta0 = (float) (2 * Math.PI / (numberOfVertices - 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {

        float theta = i * theta0;

        float c = (float) Math.cos(theta);
        float s = (float) Math.sin(theta);

        float x = radius * c;
        float y = radius * s;

        vertices[i][0] = x;
        vertices[i][1] = y;

    }
}
}
```